# How to destroy or reset Singleton instance in Java?

Tags: java, android, singleton

Singleton class

```
public class M_Singleton{
  private volatile static M_Singleton uniqueInstance=null;
  private ArraList<Integer> myArr;

  private M_Signleton{
    this.myArr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  public static M_Singleton getInstance(){
    if(uniqueInstance==null){
       synchronized (M_Signleton.class){
           if(uniqueInstance==null)
                uniqueInstance=new M_Signleton();
           }
       }
    return uniqueInstance;
  }
  public void deleteInstance(){
     uniqueInstance=null;
  }
}
```

Main class

```
M_Singleton ms=M_Singleton getInstance();
//put A-value in "MyArr"
sd.deleteInstance();
//put B-value in "MyArr"
```

I thought, there would be only B-value in MyArr
But there is only A-value.

If I change deleteInstance like this, there is only A-value still.

```
public void deleteInstance(){
     uniqueInstance=new M_Singleton();
}
```

How to destroy singleton?

Comment: If you want to change your value in object, why not use a normal class instead of Singleton class?

Comment: Singleton is a pattern for "maintaining only ONE instance of the class", if your use case is to change / modify the instance, then it is no longer a Singleton and you should consider alternatives to your problems in question.

Comment: @shizhen   In fact, the class I use has a lot of variables. After storing all the information analyzed in "A", several classes need to use the information in the singleton class. If the information to be analyzed changes,from "A" to "B", I have to delete the information in the singleton and save the new information. So I choose singleton.

Comment: Then, this is not singleton. You should not use Singleton as a place to store and maintain some status. Why not use `SharedPreference` or other means?

Comment: @shizhen thank you for comment. I will find out about **SharedPreference**

Answer (score 2):

make singleton object null for destroy singleton like this

```
uniqueInstance=null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick to *Singleton* for your case, below is a **Java reflection** way for resetting your *single instance*:

```
public static void setPrivateField(Class clazz, Object inst, String field, Object value) throws Exception {
    java.lang.reflect.Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField(field);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(inst, value);
    f.setAccessible(false);
}
```

Just call this method like below wherever you need to reset this *singleton*:

```
setPrivateField(M_Singleton.class, null, "uniqueInstance", null);
```